# how to change my background image by day_of_week

Tags: android-studio

what code for change background image in android studio java by current day name,
for example if today is monday then background image is A image,if tuesday then b image...thx

Comment: Hi & welcome to Stack Overflow! This forum is not for questions about technologies or to find somebody doing the work for free (search some freelance service for that). See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Create Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for ideas about what kind of questions can be made and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can check day's of the week and change image . Please try as follows

```
private static void getDaysOfTheWeek() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
    cal.setTime(new Date());

    switch(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)){
        case Calendar.MONDAY:
            System.out.println("image 1");
            break;
        case Calendar.TUESDAY:
            System.out.println("image 2");
            break;
        case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
            System.out.println("image 3");
            break;
        case Calendar.THURSDAY:
            System.out.println("image 4");
            break;
        case Calendar.FRIDAY:
            System.out.println("image 5");
            break;
        case Calendar.SATURDAY:
            System.out.println("image 6");
            break;
        case Calendar.SUNDAY:
            System.out.println("image 5");
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Layout file that while show image for changing background and on it show TextView That will show Text and use below code to generate bitmap image and set it  to your ImageView. Hope This will Help you

```
 private Bitmap getCustomImage(@DrawableRes int imageId,String text) {

        View customView = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.your_layout_file, null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
   TextView textView = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(text);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageId);
        customView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        customView.layout(0, 0, customMarkerView.getMeasuredWidth(), customView.getMeasuredHeight());
        customView.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(customView.getMeasuredWidth(), customView.getMeasuredHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        Drawable drawable = customView.getBackground();
        if (drawable != null)
            drawable.draw(canvas);
        customView.draw(canvas);
        return returnedBitmap;
    }
```